# Criar select usando ciclo "for"

Tags: php, html

Testei de vários maneiras, e não consigo criar um `<select/>` com um `for` em PHP.

A dúvida é simples, eu tenho um `for` que vai de `1` até `48`, e eu preciso retornar esses `48` numeros em um `select`.

Alguém sabe algum jeito de montar isso?

Comment: O número é o valor do select, o texto do select, ou ambos?

Answer (score 6):

Utilizando PHP:

```
<select name="exemplo" id="exemplo"> 
<?php
for($i=1 ; $i <49; $i++)
        echo"<option value='$i'>'$i'</option>";

?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5):

> **Nota:** essa é uma resposta a uma revisão anterior da pergunta, na qual a linguagem não estava especificada e eu assumi (erroneamente) se tratar de JavaScript.

Você pode fazer isso com métodos de manipulação do DOM (`createElement`, `appendChild`, etc), mas um meio mais simples é criar o HTML como texto mesmo e inseri-lo no `innerHTML` do seu `select`:

```js
var html = "";
for ( var i = 1 ; i <= 48 ; i++ ) {
  html += '<option value="' + i + '">' + i + "</option>";
}
document.getElementById("meuSelect").innerHTML = html;
```

```html
<select id="meuSelect"></select>
```

Alternativa com os métodos de manipulação do DOM:

```js
var meuSelect = document.getElementById("meuSelect");
for ( var i = 1 ; i <= 48 ; i++ ) {
  var opcao = document.createElement("option");
  opcao.setAttribute("value", i);
  opcao.textContent = "" + i;
  meuSelect.appendChild(opcao);
}
```

```html
<select id="meuSelect"></select>
```

Comment: Meu conceito sobre isso é bem básico, como que implementaria esse for em um input do form::helper do cakephp?

`<?= $this->Form->input('Semana',array(
'type' => 'select', 
for($i=1 ; $i <49; $i++)
echo 'options' => '{$i} Semanas'
)); ?>`

Comment: @RobertoSchon Por favor cite esse tipo de coisa na pergunta - não somente a linguagem utilizada, mas qualquer biblioteca, framework, ou o que quer que possa influenciar nas respostas recebidas. Inicialmente pensei em dar um exemplo em jQuery, mas preferi responder em JS puro pra resposta ficar mais genérica. Da mesma forma, se na pergunta só estiver citado PHP você só vai receber respostas "genéricas", enquanto a menção do cakephp pode levar alguém com experiência nessa plataforma a te dar uma ajuda mais útil. :)

Answer (score 1):

Apesar de não estar especificado, o autor parece estar usando cakePHP,

Você pode usar assim:

```
$array = array(
     '' => 'Selecione...'
);

for ($i = 1; $i < 49; ++$i) {
    if ($i === 1) {
        $array['1'] = '1 Semana';//Singular :)
    } else {
        $array[(string) $i] = $i . ' Semanas';
    }
}

echo $this->Form->input('Semana', array(
    'type' => 'select',
    'options' => $array
));
```

O resultado será algo como:

```
<div class="input">
    <label for="Semana">Field</label>
    <select id="Semana" name="data[User][Semana]">
        <option value="">Selecione...</option>
        <option value="1">1 Semana</option>
        <option value="2">2 Semanas</option>
        ...
    </select>
</div>
```